# Ribbon Classic Controls won't install in Delphi 10.4 Community Edition

Tags: delphi

I'm tying to install this package, but having problems. I can find it in GetIt, and click the Install button. It shows that it has installed...

[image]

Not sure if the lack of text in the window is an indication of anything, but when I click the Close button, it shows as installed...

[image]

However, if I close and then re-open the package manager and click the Installed radio button, the package is listed (implying it's installed), but doesn't have the green tick that other packages have, implying it's not installed...

[image]

If I select it, I see the Install button in the lower-right corner like I did when I first searched for it. If I restart Delphi, the same happens, it shows under Installed, but doesn't have the green tick, and does have the Install button when I select it.

I've tried this a few times, but it always does the same. As you can see from the last screenshot, other packages have installed OK.

Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can you see them in the component palette?

Comment: GetIt is not the test for whether a component is installed or not. Open Components->Install Packages and see if the packages are in the list and the checkbox is checked. I'd suggest you learn the basics of using Delphi and installing components, rather than just flailing about without a clue what you're doing. There are tons of decent Delphi tutorials and videos available that can help you learn the basics.

Comment: @KenWhite It does show in Install Packages, so I guess I don't need to worry about it. Didn't know about that option until you mentioned it here and in the other post, thanks. As for Delphi, I'm trying to learn it as I go along, but I had this project dropped on me, and I need to get it up and running as quickly as possible, so am trying to do both at the same time. I did spend some time learning the basics of Delphi, but my main problem here is setting up the requirements to be able to load and run this project.